# Mind + Action Ing? is it correct for ask anything to someone?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I read somewhere that if I want to ask or request something  *(very politely)*, I should use **"Mind + Action ing...?"**

- Like If I want to ask pen to any one.
  =>  *Mind giving me a pen?*
- If I talk to some one to please go market very politely
  => *Mind going to market?*

So is this a correct way to ask someone to do something very politely/respectfully?

Please clarify when I can use this. I am confused.

Comment: The phrase is a shortening of *"Do you mind..."*  It is polite, but informal.

Comment: *Mind giving me a pen*?

Comment: Don't know exactly but might be in British english we can directly speak *"Mind giving a pen?"*

Comment: ***Would** you mind ...* would be more polite, but it also depends on your tone of voice, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your examples are a shortened and less formal and thus not polite. They are NOT rude, but they are simply another way of asking for something.

The full polite/respectful version is

"Would + subject + mind [verb]ing"

e.g Would you mind lending me a pen? 
e.g Would you mind going to the market?

Th

Comment: Thanks for more clear. Instead of use Mind giving .... we should use would you giving.... ? that means *Mind giving...* is wrong to speak? Right ?

Comment: @iPatel "Would **you** mind ***lending*** me your pen?" But "Would you mind **if** I **open** the window"

Comment: Not 'would you giving' but 'would you _mind_ giving...' . Leaving out the 'Would you' (or 'Do you') makes the request much less respectful.